# How to change data before sending to ListView on Android

Tags: listview, android-studio

I wanted to change the value of a field before displaying it on listView.

Here's the part of the code where I wanted to perform the changes:

```java
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    Cursor c = getCursor();

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messagemenu_row_layout, parent, false);

    int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(MessageMenuDBHandler.COLUMN_NAME_DT);
    Long millis = c.getLong(nameCol);
    millis = millis * 1000;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
    Date resultdate = new Date(millis);
    String fdt = sdf.format(resultdate);

    Log.i(TAG, "Formatted DT: " + fdt);

    TextView textView_DT = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_dt);
    textView_DT.setText("test" + fdt);

    return v;
}
```

the data displayed on the listView did not change, it still shows the old timestamp format which is similar to '1423300445'.

Millis DT: 1423300445000
Formatted DT: Feb 07,2015 04:14

What should I do to alter the data before sending it out to listView?

Thanks!

==EDIT1==
The part where I insert record:

```java
public void onClick_addRecord(View V){
    ///// Add to MessageMenuDB /////
    // Prepare database
    MessageMenuDBHandler dbHandler = new MessageMenuDBHandler(context, null, null, 1);

    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    int ts = Integer.parseInt(tsLong.toString());

    String msg = "Sample messsage";
    String type = "Type";
    String dest = "Dest";
    String from = "From";

    Log.i(TAG, "ts: " + String.valueOf(ts));
    //(int dt, String message, String type, String dest, String from, int seen, int sent, int mo)
    MessageMenu messageMenu = new MessageMenu(
            ts, msg, type, dest, from, 0, 0, 0
    );
    dbHandler.addMessage(messageMenu);

    generateMessageList();
}
```

==EDIT2==
The database calls

```java
public class MessageMenuDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String TAG = "DBHandler";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MessageMenuDB.db";

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "messages";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DT = "dt";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TYPE = "type";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DEST = "dest";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_FROM = "frm";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SEEN = "seen"; // 2-way, Seen by us or by recipient, 0 or 1
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SENT = "sent"; // message sent to server, 0 or 1
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_MO = "mo"; // Message Originating, 1 if message was made by us



public MessageMenuDBHandler(Context context, String name,
                            SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COLUMN_NAME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_DT + " INTEGER,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_MESSAGE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_TYPE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_DEST + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_FROM + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_SEEN + " INTEGER,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_SENT + " INTEGER,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_MO + " INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addMessage(MessageMenu messageMenu) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_DT, messageMenu.getDT());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_MESSAGE, messageMenu.getMessage());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, messageMenu.getType());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_DEST, messageMenu.getDest());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_FROM, messageMenu.getFrom());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_SEEN, messageMenu.getSeen());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_SENT, messageMenu.getSent());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_MO, messageMenu.getMO());

    Log.i(TAG, "dt: " + messageMenu.getDT());
    Log.i(TAG, "msg: " + messageMenu.getMessage());
    Log.i(TAG, "type: " + messageMenu.getType());
    Log.i(TAG, "dest: " + messageMenu.getDest());
    Log.i(TAG, "from: " + messageMenu.getFrom());
    Log.i(TAG, "seen: " + messageMenu.getSeen());
    Log.i(TAG, "sent: " + messageMenu.getSent());
    Log.i(TAG, "mo: " + messageMenu.getMO());


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}


public boolean deleteMessage(int id) {

    boolean result = false;

    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME_ID + " =  " + id + "";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    MessageMenu messageMenu = new MessageMenu();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        messageMenu.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(messageMenu.getID()) });
        cursor.close();
        result = true;
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}


public Cursor query(String tableName, String orderedBy) {

    String[] projection = {COLUMN_NAME_ID, COLUMN_NAME_DT, COLUMN_NAME_MESSAGE,
        COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME_DEST, COLUMN_NAME_FROM,
        COLUMN_NAME_SEEN, COLUMN_NAME_SENT, COLUMN_NAME_MO};
    //String[] projection = {COLUMN_NAME_PRODCODE, COLUMN_NAME_DETAIL};

    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().query(tableName, projection, null, null, null, null, orderedBy);
    //getReadableDatabase().close();

    return c;
}

}
```

But I sort of wanted to modify the data before it is displayed and not before it is saved since on my actual application, the data is already there, saved and I'm not allowed to change that, I can only change the way I display the data.

==EDIT3==
This is how I populated my listView

```java
private void generateMessageList(){
    MessageMenuDBHandler dbHandler = new MessageMenuDBHandler(context, null, null, 1);

    Cursor c = dbHandler.query(MessageMenuDBHandler.TABLE_NAME,
            MessageMenuDBHandler.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " DESC");

    String[] from = new String[]{MessageMenuDBHandler.COLUMN_NAME_FROM,
            MessageMenuDBHandler.COLUMN_NAME_MESSAGE,
            MessageMenuDBHandler.COLUMN_NAME_DT};

    int[] to = {
            R.id.list_from,
            R.id.list_msg,
            R.id.list_dt
    };

    MessageMenuAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter = new MessageMenuAdapter(
            this,
            //android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            R.layout.messagemenu_row_layout,
            c,
            from,
            to,
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    listView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

    listItemClickListener();
}
```

==EDIT4==
So I tried to edit the query as per advice of @DerGolem, but I'm a bit lost on  how to return the new value back into the cursor variable c.  Tried to look at the code completion c. to see if something I could use but all I see are mostly get... functions.  Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

```java
public Cursor query(String tableName, String orderedBy) {

    String[] projection = {COLUMN_NAME_ID, COLUMN_NAME_DT, COLUMN_NAME_MESSAGE,
        COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME_DEST, COLUMN_NAME_FROM,
        COLUMN_NAME_SEEN, COLUMN_NAME_SENT, COLUMN_NAME_MO};
    //String[] projection = {COLUMN_NAME_PRODCODE, COLUMN_NAME_DETAIL};

    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().query(tableName, projection, null, null, null, null, orderedBy);
    //getReadableDatabase().close();

    int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(MessageMenuDBHandler.COLUMN_NAME_DT);
    Long millis = c.getLong(nameCol);
    millis = millis * 1000;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
    Date resultdate = new Date(millis);
    String fdt = sdf.format(resultdate);
    /* now how am I supposed to get the value of fdt back to that c? xD */
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at my code @DerGolem, I appreciate the help

Comment: sorry about the mess on my codes, I'm still trying to figure out how to properly display my codes.

Comment: Thanks for your patience @DerGolem, let me put up that part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first approach made it complicated. Instead of my old code:

```java
MessageMenuAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter = new MessageMenuAdapter(
        this,
        R.layout.messagemenu_row_layout,
        c,
        from,
        to,
        CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
listView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);
```

I just stick to plainly using SimpleCursorAdaper without my customize MessageMenuAdapter. Replaced the code with:

```java
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.messagemenu_row_layout,
            c,
            from,
            to);

    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 1) {
                Long millis = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
                millis = millis * 1000;
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
                Date resultdate = new Date(millis);
                String fdt = sdf.format(resultdate);
                ((TextView) view).setText(fdt);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The solution is the setViewBinder.  At least this works for my particular problem.

Thanks to @DerGolem for being very patient in suggesting solutions.